# How do I open this radiator TRV valve?

Tags: radiator

[image: Pic of TRV]

The radiator is cold at the bottom and I suspect that the pin is stuck. I bled the radiator and there was no sludge.

Comment: You won't necessarily see sludge when you bleed the radiator. It is not difficult to remove the radiator and flush it.

Comment: Andrew, we had the radiators flushed over the summer, so it is unlikely to have sludge. How do I get to the pin of the TRV? What do I have to turn and in what direction? It is stuck quite tight and not a shape that lends itself to a wrench.

Comment: You describe the symptoms of sludge in the radiator and decide that there is a problem with the valve. Even if the TRV was stuck partially open, the radiator would eventually get to an even(ish) temperature. Or are you saying that you cannot turn the control at all? In that case, replacing the valve will be the best option. Unless the valve needs the white bit pushed in to allow it to be rotated past the blue symbol.